# Rails multitenancy and dynamic routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

The context of the problem is a form of multitenancy application.
Different objects have access to a central set of classes and methods.
However, views *could* be entirely re-configurable from a central method.
Also, some ad hoc methods might be devised for a given object, which we'll refer to as `@site`.

Thus,

```
class SharedmethodsController < ApplicationController
class SitexController < SharedmethodsController
```

where `Sitex` includes the unique name of a site

Views would be nominally be housed in a subdirectory `sites/sitex`

So while the rails routing guide provides a mechanism for accessing a well identified [route from multiple objects](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#creating-paths-and-urls-from-objects)

```
resources :magazines do
  resources :ads
end
```

this only provides a hook to the objects's `id`.

The first problem is that we don't have is a definition of the controller's name, nor a clear idea of where to save the controller and views, as per the rails convention.  The symbol refers to a static class, thus this means for each new site, a new set of ressources needs to be declared.

The second problem is how to best configure the views.  The Sitex views would in the majority of the cases be the same as the inherited Sharedmethods.  Generating Symlinks at the creation of the Site would be one alternative.  Defaulting to Rails logic might actually be easier as it would look in sitex, sharedmethods and views folder; potential naming conflicts are however on the horizon.

All this is possible to adjust manually (and could possibly be preferable in terms of focus on the actual issues at hand for a given Site), but is there not a logic to allow for any new case in this scenario?

Comment: For the views, why are you not storing your views in the database? And have a fallback to the default view on the filesystem?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "Different objects have access to a central set of classes and methods." and "The first problem is that we don't have is a definition of the controller's name, nor a clear idea of where to save the controller and views, as per the rails convention.". It's not very clear unfortunately. Can you give an example of an URL and to which controller you want to get it dispatched same as what an ad-hoc method should be?

Comment: `sitex/12/edit` `sitey/47` `sitez/439/edit`  where, for example, the show and edit actions would be inherited from the Sharedmethod class - then `sitex/moonjump` `sitey/garbagedump` or `siteq/arkanesearch` would have their own methods.

Comment: What would these custom actions do and how would they get defined? Can the tenant define these and what would it do for instance?

Comment: The actions would not be defined by the tenant; so, yes, a ressource block would be introduced by developer.  Their scope is boundless, but always under developer control.

Comment: So you want and need to deploy each new tenant? They can't signup on their own? It's still not really clear what these custom actions will do. A concrete example with an example tenant and desired routes would help, it's all very vague. Please edit the original question with these information.

Comment: No, there is no individual signup; some actions are shared, some are built ad hoc. Say `sitey` wants to present an list with an attribute that is not normally in the index (or view) and sorted by said attribute; both that collection and the individual member require specific actions. Placing them in the controller of shared actions will make that controller grow to undesirable levels.